How to remove label on an action in Filament php
The title says it all. Trying to remove the label on an edit action. Or any action
I've checked stackoverflow and github
I can't seem to find a straightforward answer and I have a feeling that there is one since in filament everything is just a 1 line thing solves a complex problem

UPDATE: Found the answer. when calling an action like edit or delete you can simply add
->label('') to your code and just the action icon will be displayed

Did you not find that this leaves some space to the right of the icon though, i.e. https://pasteboard.co/JhTJG0oMGe9Q.png

you can change ->label(' ') to ->label('')

You can use icon button if you want to show only icon, and add tooltip for more readability like this
Tables\Actions\Action::make('print')
    ->icon('heroicon-o-printer')
    ->tooltip('Print Honorarium')
    ->iconButton()


thats another method
